# adb can't find ViewSonic ViewPad 7 on Mac OS X

Tags: android, terminal, adb

I can't get adb to recognize my device (ViewSonic ViewPad 7).

On my device under Settings/Applications/Development/ "USB debugging" is checked.

When I plug in my USB cable I see two ongoing items in the task bar: "USB debugging connected" and "USB connected".

However if I then go into my Mac' (Mac OS X 10.6.6) Terminal.app I can't find the device.

```
$ adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 
$ adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.26
```

Anyone have any idea what else I can try?

EDIT, 2-5-2011:

For a little more background it seems that the same version of adb on an older Macbook running OS 10.6.5 IS able to detect my device. Both versions of adb are 1.0.26.

Comment: Did you follow this URL: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah hah! Breakthrough!

It seems if I leave USB Debugging enabled and toggle USB tethering (Settings -> Wireless & Networks -> Tethering & Portable Hotspot) then the device is listed under the *adb devices* command.

Definitely a bug - not sure what the cause is but is seems more likely an Android 2.2.1 issue than an OSX issue at this point.

Comment: How did you enable Tethering..using an app like PdaNet?

Comment: In the Settinge app: Settings -> Wireless & Networds -> Tethering & Portable Hotspot

Comment: I'm not sure how you found that out, but you're a life saver. Couldn't figure out for the life of me why I couldn't see the ViewSonic ViewPad 7 on my OSX Eclipse install.

Comment: Yah. The way I found out was by banging my head against my desk for a few hours. I eventually became delirious and started just randomly flipping switches in the Settings :)

Answer (score 0):

After installing USB driver, you need to find vendor id for ViewSonic and then try following in .android folder in your home directory (on Linux/OS X):

> echo ViewSonic_Vendor_id >>
>   ~/.android/adb_usb.ini

EDIT:
From [this source](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/tegra/docs/android_tegra_250_5421622.pdf) (page 10) looks like 0x955 is the vendor id for your device. Please try:

> echo 0x955 >>
>   "~/.android/adb_usb.ini"

Comment: I'm definitely willing to give it a shot but it doesn't seem like this is necessary on Mac OS X according to the URL you mentioned above (developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up). Either way: what's the vendor ID? It's not listed on that page and googling isn't turning it up.

Comment: 1) Doesn't work. 2) I Think you mean echo "0x955" >> ~/.android/adb_usb.ini (quotes in the wrong place) 3) That's an nvidia page you're linking to? My device is the ViewSonic ViewPad 7. On this page (http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids) I found ViewSonic Corp. listed os 0x0543 - but this doesn't work either.

Comment: @awolf : I have removed quotes in my answer (which was little confusing, sorry). I got the PDF url from here - Getting ADB on Viewsonic tablet to work (http://209.250.2.82/index.php?topic=10445.msg85267#msg85267). On that page, one of users was able to do use adb successfully.

Comment: @awolf Looks like its 0x955 is the vendor id for G pad.

Comment: Regarding your command: there should be quotes around 0x955 and no quotes around the path (at least on Mac OS X). The nvidia guide got it wrong too. Either way, this solution doesn't work. Entering the USB vendor IDs shouldn't be necessary on Mac.

Comment: Did you try this link: http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-x-faq/74089-how-setting-up-adb-mac-osx-your-droid-x.html

Comment: Assuming the USB debugging is enabled on your device. Settings --> Applications --> Development --> USB Debugging.

Comment: That link has nothing tangibly different then the official tutorial and is not related to the ViewSonic ViewPad. And yes, USB debugging is enabled on the device (as I said in my initial question).